# Compile a new console application from a running application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, exe

Is it possible to create an application in c# that can itself create another application from source code it creates dynamically?

for example, application 1 runs and asks you some basic questions. then uses the answers to those questions to compile a brand new exe for you containing your answers inside the source code?

I hope that makes sense!

Martyn

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# execute a string as code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511376/c-sharp-execute-a-string-as-code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could .NET be parsed and evaluated at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327831/could-net-be-parsed-and-evaluated-at-runtime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can using the `CSharpCodeProvider` class.  See this code project article which gives you the general idea:

[Compiling and Executing Code at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/runtimecompiling.aspx)

Comment: My GoogleFu was weak today! Good link, just what I was looking for. Haven't had a really good look, but it looks like that class is just the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to create a different application every time?

Creating a generic version of that application and then configuring it using a file from the other application might be easier.

Comment: Im creating a wrapper for another application, so the application I am creating will take another exe file and some other bits as inputs, then compile a new EXE that will contain the file and install them all. Kind of a mini installer.